# Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I have an outlook add-in that creates notification message like this:

[screenshot from inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqA5K.png)

And the code for adding the notification looks like this:

Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("action", message);

When I hover on the notification in outlook it has a tool-tip. Is there a way to customize the tool-tip text? As the Notification message has a restriction of 150 characters, it would be nice to add further details in the tool-tip. If possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible to customize the notification's tooltip. I believe the tooltip is there on Windows in case the notification is wider than the message form, since its text doesn't wrap to the next line.

If you would like, you add a request for this customization to the Outlook add-in [UserVoice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins).